# What part is marking code TV608?

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

I am looking for help to identify some chips marked TV608 on a Dahua Network Video Recorder. It seems to be not producing the required voltage output to drive the network devices connected to it. These chips are, I believe, SOT23-6 body type with 3 legs each side for a total of 6 legs. They seem to be some kind of PWM/SMPS controller.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `not producing the required voltage` ... maybe it's ovetloaded

Comment: I need the actual part number as the marked code of TV608. is typically an internal manufacturer code that is different from the part's real ID part number

Comment: Welcome, could you provide a closeup photo of the IC? Also a photo of the pcb would be helpful!